# text input fill width of container

Tags: css

I have an input inside of a container with varying width that will often change not only between page loads, but also while the user is on the page. I am trying to make it so that the input always fills the container. The method I currently use works perfectly in some browsers, but not all.

html:

```
<div class="container">
      <input type="text" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

The padding makes it such that I can't just set the width to 100%, as this causes the input to overflow by 8px from the padding. On certain browsers (at least Chrome on Windows) the input is not affected by the `left` and `right` css tags and just stays the default input width. I know I could do it with js, but I would rather find a simpler solution. Is there any cross-browser way to do this with pure css and no js?

Comment: I would drop the padding and set left & right to a few %, but this is just a workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use the css property `box-sizing: border-box;`, the padding will be no problem and you can use `width:100%`.

See here: [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Here is an example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/AdUMudif/2/edit?html,css,output)

CSS:

```
.fill {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%
}
```

HTML:

```
<input class="fill" type="text"/>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. There are other answers to this problem on SO that are getting marked up, that have all sorts of subtle flaws. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/f5g2L/

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 80%; //change to whatever
}
input {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    font-size: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a negative margin of -2px to offset your padding on the left along with box-sizing with browser prefixes... something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/LKxcv/

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: inherit;
}
input {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;    
}
```